# Does this occur because there is an NaN?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of floats, and when I try to convert it into series or dataframe

```
code
000001.SZ     1.305442
000002.SZ     1.771655
000004.SZ     2.649862
000005.SZ     1.373074
000006.SZ     1.115238
               ...    
601512.SH    16.305734
688123.SH    53.395579
603995.SH    19.598881
688268.SH    70.174454
002972.SZ    19.644900
300811.SZ    24.042762
688078.SH    86.263280
603109.SH          NaN
Length: 3753, dtype: float64

df = pd.DataFrame(data = mylist,columns = ["std_r_in20days"])
print(df)       
s = pd.Series(mylist)
print(s)
```

The result is:

```
 std_r_in20days
0             NaN

0    code
000001.SZ     1.305442
000002.SZ     1.77...
dtype: object

AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values (i.e. inferred_type is 'string', 'unicode' or 'mixed')
```

Does this occur because there is an NaN in mylist? If so, how can I fix it? I don't want to delete the row with NaN but just leave them there

Comment: The code you have shown us wouldn't trigger that error...

Comment: What is `mylist` ?

Comment: mylist is the dataset I posted

Answer (score 0):

```
Ser=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,None],[2,3,4,5,np.nan]])
Ser=Ser.replace(np.nan,0)
```

You can do it like this. There are also other functions in pandas like fillna().:)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the whole row , you can just replace those values with 0 using pandas function

`df.fillna(0)`

Also, learn to perform null check in the beginning of your script using

```
df.isna().sum().sum()
```

This will give you the number of NaN values in your whole dataframe